# PHP Parameters sqlsrv_query , sqlsrv_fetch_array warning

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I'm receiving this warning in PHP

> Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
> given in C:\xampp\htdocs\change_logo_process.php on line 7
>
> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
> boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\change_logo_process.php on line 8
>
> Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
> given in C:\xampp\htdocs\change_logo_process.php on line 14 Your
> Guild Logo Has Been Set .NOTICE: This update might take effect after
> 24 hrs OR after server restart!

This is my code:

```
<?php
include_once ("include/config.php");
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "RohanGame", "UID" => $UID, "PWD" => $PASS);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($_POST['group1'] == "1") {
    $sql = "select master_id from dbo.TNGuildMark where master_id = (select master_id from dbo.TNGuild where name = '$_POST[gbox]')";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    if ($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
        $sql1 = "update dbo.TNGuildMark set mark = 0xff where master_id = (select master_id from dbo.TNGuild where name = '$_POST[gbox]')";
        $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1);
        echo "Your Guild Logo Has Been Set .NOTICE: This update might take effect after 24 hrs OR after server restart!";
    } else {
        $sql2 = "insert into dbo.TNGuildMark(mark,master_id) select 0xff, master_id from dbo.TNGuild where name = '$_POST[gbox]'";
        $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);
        echo "Your Guild Logo Has Been Set .NOTICE: This update might take effect after 24 hrs OR after server restart!";
    }
}
```

Comment: `sqlsrv_connect()` failed and returned `FALSE` instead of a connection resource. You need to check for the error.

Comment: Use [sqlsrv_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php) to get the details of the error.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampp\htdocs\change_logo_proccess.php on line 582

Comment: That error is unrelated to the code you posted. There's no `$end` in the question.

Comment: You probably forgot a `;` at the end of the line before.

Comment: thanks for the help your first comment helped a lot at first i didnt get it but when i focused ideas coming in hehe thanks , i just checked the include/config.php and there's no : $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo); so i linked the include/dbconn.php which has the ($serverName, $connectionInfo) tag